# Launching a command from a physical keyboard shortcut

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments

I have the Logitech Ergo K860 keyboard that has some programmable keys. I want a key to launch a specific RDP connection.

Just to test it out, I tried:

```
CMD
```

and it launched a Command window.

OK, so onto what I'm trying to actually accomplish. This works from the command line directly:

```
MSTSC "\\path\My Desktop.rdp" /v:MyComputerName /f
```

I tried this (and many variations)

```
CMD /c MSTSC "\\path\My Desktop.rdp" /v:MyComputerName /f
```

as the application to be launched by the key press, but nothing happens.
What do I need to enter into the keyboard's utility to get it to correctly launch that RDP connection?

Comment: What is the name of your utility?

Comment: [Logitech Options](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options)

Comment: Just a guess - try to double the anti-slashes: `CMD /c MSTSC "\\\\path\My Desktop.rdp" /v:MyComputerName /f
`

Comment: Nope. And unfortunately there's no feedback or error. Just doesn't work. :(

Comment: Try just: `MSTSC "C:\path\My Desktop.rdp" /v:MyComputerName /f`.

Comment: No, but that doesn't work from the command line, either. I need to use UNC share path.

Comment: This is illogical, unless your `.rdp` is in error.

Comment: Not sure because the .rdp works just fine. And I tried copying to the local C-drive and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Post perhaps the file.

Comment: Good idea. I don't see a way for me to upload the RDP file here, so I posted it [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WFSKWRMVGLABs5V8UADuz7b5wH3jN4XT?usp=sharing) to Google Drive.

Comment: Any ideas of what might be the issue based on the RDP file I posted?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. The only theory I have is that the connection is wrong, meaning wrong domain or similar.